# Using ajax and php to insert data to MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I feel like I'm probably about 90% of the way there, and just need some help with that last 10%.  I've looked at a number of different examples, and tried to piece together a solution, but haven't figured it out, so I'm looking for some guidance.

I have a small html page, with a little javascript, and a short .php that is adding the received data to a database.

I can see that the code is getting into the ajax function, and then into the insert function.  But it's not actually doing the insert.  I suspect that it's never sending the data off to the php file, but I don't know that for sure.

Here's the html code:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <script type ="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            function ajaxFunction(){
                var ajaxRequest;
                    alert("enter ajax"); //just a testing line
                try{
                    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
                } catch (e) {
                    try {
                        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                    } catch (e) {
                        try {
                            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                        } catch (e) {
                            alert("Your browser broke!");
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }

            ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
                    var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('responseDiv');
                    ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
                        }
                }

                alert("enter insert");  //just for testing
                var type = $('#type').val();
                var vintner = $('#vintner').val();

                var myData = {"type": type, "vintner": vintner,};

                $.ajax({
                    url: "bottleAdd.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: "myData",
                    success: function(data, status, xhr)
                    {
                        $("$bottleAdd").html(data);
                        $("type").val();
                        $("vintner").val();
                        }
                });
            }

        </script>

        <title>Simple Add</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="addBottle">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Type: <input type="text" id="type" /></td>
                    <td>Vintner: <input type="text" id="vintner" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><button onClick="ajaxFunction()">Save Bottle Now</button></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div id="responseDiv">Response will appear here</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here's the php

```
<?php
require_once 'login.php';
$conn = mysqli_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database) or die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());

$wineType = $_POST['type'];
$vintner = $_POST['vintner'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO bottleSimple (winetype, vintner)"
        . " values ('$wineType', '$vintner')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "Successfully Inserted";
} else {
    echo "Insertion Failed<br />";
    echo $sql;
}
?>
```

I know there are some things to do in the php (prevent sql injection for example).  But right now, I'm less concerned about that, and more about just figuring out how to get this to run correctly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: What's data in your Ajax's success?

Comment: You mixed regular "naked" AJAX with jQuery's ajax (the $.ajax). Remove all the code up to the $.ajax. Add jQuery before the script tag - and you'll be good to go.

Comment: i think your problem in here `data: "myData",`  .check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mixed plain JS AJAX with [jQuery's ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) wrapper.

Change your code to the following:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Simple Add</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type ="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        var type = $('#type').val();
        var vintner = $('#vintner').val();
        var myData = {"type": type, "vintner": vintner};
        $.ajax({
            url: "bottleAdd.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: myData,
            success: function(data) {
                $("#responseDiv").html(data);
            }  
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

The rest is without a change.

That way you will use jQuery AJAX.

By the way, it is a good practice to place meta tags a the beginning of your head tag, because tag like the charset will cause the browser to start reading your page again from the beginning.

Comment: Thank you Ron.  That has certainly made a difference.  I assumed it was something relatively simple like mixing up different version so ajax.  What I am seeing now is that blank record is being added to the database, as opposed to the data that I'm entering.  Also, I am not getting anything back from the php.  The php is supposed to return something and display that to the screen.  Any thoughts on how I've messed that one up?

Comment: First of all, I've just noticed that I've copied a piece of your code to the success function that was wrong. I've updated the answer.

Comment: You need to check your insert into section. INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)

Comment: I'm using Ron's advice for now, and have changed the code to what you suggested.  But now, I'm getting a blank row added to the database each time I refresh the page.  I am getting Successfully Inserted back. But I'm also getting Undefined Index type in .../.php, for the $wineType = $_POST['type'];
$vintner = $_POST['vintner']; lines.

Comment: I guess I was next to the computer too long today. Notice the "data" part of the request. Change from data: "myData" to data: myData (without the quotes) and that should work. I've updated the answer.

Comment: And also remove the last comma from var myData = {"type": type, "vintner": vintner, };. The answer was updated for this as well.

Comment: I have figured out that last thing that was causing me trouble.  I needed to re-add the function ajaxFunction() { ... } to wrap around the everything inside the <script>.  Once I re-added that, everything seemed to be solved.  I am no longer getting blank rows added when I first load the page.  Instead, I'm getting rows added when I click the button, with the data I've entered.  Excellent!  Thank you all very much for your help and advice.

Answer (score 0):

You mixed two invoke methods of XHR - the native method and jQuery method. 
If You go for native method with creating native xhr objct, You should operate only with the ajaxRequest variable which keeps the native XHR object. The solution is remove the code staring with

```
$.ajax
```

and, after define the onstatechange event, add Your request params, and finnaly send your xhr. So:

```
function ajaxFunction() {
        var ajaxRequest;
        try {
            ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {
                try {
                    ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                } catch (e) {
                    alert("Your browser broke!");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (ajaxRequest.readyState === 4) {

                var data = ajaxRequest.responseText;
                console.log(data);
                // do something with response data...
            }
        }

        var type = 'atype';
        var vintner = 'avintner';


        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("type", type);
        formData.append("vintner", vintner);
        ajaxRequest.open('POST', 'bottleAdd.php', true); 
        ajaxRequest.send(formData);

    }
```

should work.

Comment: Based on your comment and Ron's, clearly there are different ways to do this.  Is there reason why someone would choose one over the other?  Is one more widely supported?  Is one easier to implement?  Is one "more correct"?

Comment: My solution does not require any JS libraries as jQuery - is using "native" DOM XHR Object. So, this will work on every modern browser without including any additional scripts. If You define $.ajax, jQuery have to use this method anyway. So, by using this method, you (and your client's browser) are freed from - very often - rendundant jQuery abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:** you may wrong use this code `"mydata"` it change to `mydata`..

for see result look in console.

```js
  function ajaxFunction() {
    var ajaxRequest;
    alert("enter ajax"); //just a testing line
    try {
      ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e) {
      try {
        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
      } catch (e) {
        try {
          ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
          alert("Your browser broke!");
          return false;
        }
      }
    }

    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (ajaxRequest.readyState == 4) {
        var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('responseDiv');
        ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
      }
    }

    alert("enter insert"); //just for testing
    var type = $('#type').val();
    var vintner = $('#vintner').val();

    var myData = {
      "type": type,
      "vintner": vintner,
    };

    $.ajax({
      url: "http://stackoverflow.com/index.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: myData,
      success: function(data, status, xhr) {
        $("$bottleAdd").html(data);
        $("type").val();
        $("vintner").val();
      }
    });
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>

  <title>Simple Add</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="addBottle">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Type:
          <input type="text" id="type" />
        </td>
        <td>Vintner:
          <input type="text" id="vintner" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button onClick="ajaxFunction()">Save Bottle Now</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="responseDiv">Response will appear here</div>
</body>

</html>
```